# WinMain compiles, but wWinMain does not in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, winmain

So I'm trying to create a window in **CodeBlocks** using Win32, and so far only this version of WinMain works ( note: this is just a simple and naive example ):

```
#include <windows.h>

INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow ) {
    MessageBox( NULL, "Title", "Message", MB_OKCANCEL );
    return 0;
}
```

But this version does not:

```
#include <windows.h>

INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow ) {
    MessageBox( NULL, "Title", "Message", MB_OKCANCEL );
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, the latter expects the 3rd argument to be a pointer to a string of wide characters, while the former does not. But when I compile in CodeBlocks, all I get is this message:

> *undefined reference to WinMain@16*

Apparently CodeBlocks is expecting the version of WinMain that doesn't receive a LPWSTR value as argument.
My question is, how do I configure CodeBlocks so that it compiles with wWinMain?

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error.  You should be linking to the library that contains the function in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wWinMain` is compiler specific. It is supported by Visual Studio. Code::Block is usually setup with MinGW, it will compile `wWinMain` but it gives link error because it doesn't recognize `wWinMain` as the entry point, it is still looking for `WinMain` entry point.

You can just use the first version of `WinMain`, then use `GetCommandLineW()` for Unicode command line. Example:

```
int argc;
wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW( GetCommandLineW(), &argc );
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    //output argv[i]
}
```

There is a difference however between `lpCmdLine` and `GetCommandLineW`. See documentation

[WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx):

> `lpCmdLine`: The command line for the application, excluding the program name

[GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx):

> `GetCommandLineW()`: The command-line string for the current process

Note, you should use Visual Studio if you can. It's free!

Comment: *"`GetCommandLineW()` includes the path of the executable as well as arguments."* - No, it returns the command line as set up by the process calling `CreateProcess`. It is a common **convention** to pass repeat the module name as the first argument, but there is no requirement to do so, and there certainly is nothing to enforce this. *"Note, you should use Visual Studio if you can. It's free!"* - Arguably even more importantly, VS defaults to Unicode project settings (unlike Code::Blocks).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I edited the question, tried to fix that comment.

Comment: GCC is a really nice compiler, it's such a shame that the Windows tooling is so pathetic. I mean really, the lack of comprehensive Unicode support is ridiculous. Someone should really work on improving MinGW.... A clean-room port of the MSVC runtime libraries does not seem like it would be difficult, just rather time-consuming.

Comment: @CodyGray: Porting the CRT **is** difficult. I wouldn't even know where to start to implement exception handling. And do it in a way that's different enough from MS' implementation to keep legal issues out of the way.